# xCode 12.5 swift 5.4 type inference issue, result not used

Tags: swift, xcode

Hello I installed xcode 12.5 yesterday and I had a working project that I uploaded using xcode 12.3 3 days ago, I noticed after installing xcode 12.5 the following issue :

[image: xcode type inference issue]

and to fix the issue I had to specify the `list` variable type as:
[image]

I need to know is it an issue in the compiler that it is not reliable to be used, or the semantics of the language is updated !!

Comment: You have not given enough info to allow the issue to be reproduced. If I supply my own initializers for DeliveryStatus and ModelDeliveryOrderFilterInput, your code compiles just fine without those warnings. Please supply a [mcve], and please do not post pictures of code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the explicit type, try putting a `return` keyword inside the closure:

```
return ModelDeliveryOrderFilterInput...
```

This should clarify your intentions to the compiler.

Comment: my issue here is that for working large projects updating to latest version of xcode may results in unforeseen issues such as this, the `map` function should inferred the the usage of the returned value of `ModelDeliveryOrderFilterInput` constructor, not inferring that the map function body returns `Void` : `()`

Comment: The question is, did my suggestion solve the issue with this line of code. Please test it. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, another possibility would be to try putting those three lines onto one line. I suspect the compiler is confused and doesn't realize this is a "one-liner".

Comment: no, putting the code in one line did not change anything and BTW it was the first thing I tested before asking my question.